# Elementary OS 5 wingpanel does not show standard icons

Tags: release-juno, wingpanel

Hi apart from sound network etc (standard) wingpanel is refusing to show apps icons like dropbox, shutter, copyq

Comment: https://github.com/isneezy/wingpanel-indicator-dropbox

Answer (score 3):

You need to manually install `wingpanel-indicator-ayatana` in order to show again third part icons. There are some tutorials on internet showing how to do that. Note this is not a recommended action from Elementary developers, so you are on your own

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that, but didnt want to muck around with the installation. I had thought it was my fault in installation.  Developers, if you read this please comment as I cannot for the life of me understand why you would put out something that does not by default include tray icons; this will surely drive away new users?

Answer (score 1):

Systemtray as we know it are not supported anymore in eOS (nor in Gnome Shell). But I was reading some months ago, that some made a hack for it with more or less success. You may search Stackexchange to find it.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, this is going from bad to worse. I did try the ayatana wingpanel, but that made no difference. However, trying to install Dropbox from Elementary own Applications, dropbox does not work. Ive tried various versions of Dropbox and still it does not instantiate. I would guess 50% of users would use Dropbox. Never before has it been a difficulty in installation and Ive been using PC for 40 years. I can understand that Elementary OS may wish for a stable environment at the risk of some apps not working, but they have chosen a shaky path IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Elementary 5.1.2 Hera:

```
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop .config/autostart/
```

Change line 7 from:

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;
```

to

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;
```

Then I downloaded [this package](https://launchpad.net/~yunnxx/+archive/ubuntu/elementary/+files/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r30+pkg17+r1~daily~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb) and installed it with

```
sudo dpkg -i wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r30+pkg17+r1~daily~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb
```

After logging out and back in again, the problematic applications (slack, nextcloud, etc) worked fine.

Comment: Ive moved to Ubuntu Budgie. No such problem. Elementary OS was great, but IMHO Budgie is better.